# Setting up ROS package in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, clion, catkin

I am using CLion (C++ IDE) for editing a ROS package. I was able to open a package by opening the `CMakeLists.txt` file. But, I get an error,

> "FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that
>   no ROS setup.sh was sourced before"

How do I solve this problem? Will I be able to `make` the project in CLion (If so, how do I) after I make changes to the code or do I have to `catkin_make` in a separate terminal?

Comment: Every time you open a terminal it automatically (or manually with the `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash` command) retrieves catkin environmental variables. For this reason CLion can't find them by itself. Have a look at this workaround: http://answers.ros.org/question/210534/jetbrains-clion-ide-setup-for-ros/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this (for Linux):

1. Open a command line
2. Run  *catkin_make*  on your package.
3. *source* your *catkin_workspace/devel/setup.bash* file  e.g. *source ~/my_dev_folder/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash*
4. Start CLion from *[CLion install dir]/bin/clion.sh* e.g. *cd ~/Downloads/clion-1.2.4/bin  &&  ./clion.sh*

CLion should then start with knowledge about the packages in your catkin workspace, through the local environment variables set up by the setup.bash file.

Comment: Adding to the answers by whurobocon&Siong Thye Goh, and Darren H&zx485;  CLion docs now _do_ include good advice on ROS integration but you should skim the whole page because there's a lot of points covered.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2018.3/ros-setup-tutorial.html

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that the configuration advice as described on jetbrains help website linked by @willc might not work when using `catkin_tools` / `catkin build` instead of `catkin_make`. I came across this issue myself and posted a corresponding solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343315/2422098

Answer (score 4):

To add on to what *WillC* suggested, you can also modify the desktop entry to start the application from bash instead of manually doing so.

To do this, edit the desktop file located at

```
~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop
```

by modifying the line containing `Exec=` to

```
Exec=bash -i -c "/INSTALL_LOCATION/clion-2016.3.2/bin/clion.sh" %f
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what WillC suggested,CLion reload the last cmake compiling result by default.

However, if you failed to find catkin.cmake during the last attempt even though you source the devel/setup.bash and open CLion, you also cannot find catkin.cmake.

You should click File --> Reload Cmake Project and you should get the right result.